# Define a normal subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

$N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if $aNa^{-1}$ is a subset of $N$ for all elements $a $ contained in $G$. Assume, $aNa^{-1} = \{ana^{-1}|n \in N\}$.

Prove that in that case $aNa^{-1}= N.$

If $x$ is in $N$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, for any element $g$ in $G$,  $gxg^{-1}$ is in $G$. Suppose $x$ is in $N$, and $y=axa^{-1}$ as is defined. Since $N$ is normal, $aNa^{-1}$ is a subset of N. 
$x= a^{-1}ya$. Given that $x$ is in $N$, and $x=a^{-1}ya$, $y$ is also in $N$. If $y$ is in N, then $axa^{-1}$ is also in $N$. $X$ is in $aNa^{-1}$.

Does the proof make sense?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for me. What is $X$?

Usually, for proving that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, one would start by showing that 

1. Closure. For any $x,y\in H$, $xy\in H$. 
2. Existence of identity. If $e\in G$ is the identity, then $e\in H$ as well. 
3. Existence of inverse. For any $x\in H$, $x^{-1} \in H$

Try proving these three principles for the specified subgroup (i.e. $A$), and you should be fine.

Comment: @IvanWangsa Sorry, the statement to be proved was written incorrectly. The issue is that the definition of a normal subgroup is different in this problem. I'm not sure that I've approached it right or not.

Comment: As far as I know, that's the usual normal subgroup definition that I'm familiar with. Why does $x=a^{-1}ya \in N$ imply $y\in N$? And also, if $y=axa^{-1}\in N$, why does that imply $x\in aNa^{-1}$?

Comment: Does $x$ = $a^{-1}ya$ imply that $xA$ and $yA$ are in the same coset of $N$ in $G$? I was not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, we have $aNa^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $a\in G$. This is equivalent to saying $aN\subseteq Na$ for all $a\in G$. (Why?)

Thus, we simply need to show $Na\subseteq aN$ for all $a\in G$.

To this end, take $x\in Na$. Then $x=n_1a$ for some $n_1\in N$, and so $a^{-1}x=a^{-1}n_1a=(an_2a^{-1})^{-1}$. (What should $n_2$ be for this to make sense? Why can I do this?)

Now, because $N$ is normal, $an_2a^{-1}\in N$. But this also implies $(an_2a^{-1})^{-1}\in N$ (Why?) and therefore $a^{-1}x\in N$. Hence, we can write $a^{-1}x=n_3$ for some $n_3\in N$. So $x=an_3$ meaning $x\in aN$.

Hence we have $Na\subseteq aN$, and thus $Na=aN$; or, $aNa^{-1}=N$. However, our choice of $a$ was arbitrary so we have proven our claim for all $a\in G$.

Comment: Should $n2$ be $n1^{-1}$? You can do this to prove it is true for any $a$ in $G$.

Comment: Yes, $n_2=n_1^{-1}$, but I don't understand your follow up comment. I am asking: why does it not matter that I replace $n_1^{-1}$ with $n_2$?

Comment: Is it because N is normal?

Comment: Note quite. It is because $N$ is a subgroup, and subgroups are closed under inverses. Since $n_1\in N$, we know $n_1^{-1}\in N$, and I'm essentially just giving that element a different name for simplicity.

Comment: So the properties of subgroups are being used. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused as to how you got to your last step. Here's my version.

---

Suppose that $aNa^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $a \in G$. Then to show that equality holds, it suffices to show that $bNb^{-1} \supseteq N$ for all $b \in G$. To this end, choose any $b \in G$ and choose any $x \in N$. We want to show that $x \in bNb^{-1}$.

Now recall that $x \in N$ and that $aNa^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $a \in G$. Thus, by taking $a = b^{-1}$, it follows that:
$$
(b^{-1})x(b^{-1})^{-1} = b^{-1}xb \in b^{-1}Nb \subseteq N
$$
so that $b^{-1}xb \in N$. But then we're done, since:
$$
x = exe = (bb^{-1})x(bb^{-1}) = b\underbrace{(b^{-1}xb)}_{\in ~ N}b^{-1} \in bNb^{-1}
$$
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to see where the result comes from. If $N$ is normal,
$$\begin{align*}
aNa^{-1}&\subset N\\
aN&\subset Na.
\end{align*}$$
But the definition is symmetric in $a$! Swapping the roles of $a$ and $a^{-1}$, we also get $Na\subset aN$. Thus $aN=Na$, which gives you $aNa^{-1}=N$.

Philosophical aside: Groups can be annoying to work with when elements don't commute. However, oftentimes the next best thing is knowing that certain **subgroups** commute. That's what it means to be normal: you commute with all elements. All the important properties of normal subgroups (especially the formation of quotients) follow from this observation.

Comment: Commutative(ness) of subgroups is key to normal groups. I'll remember that. Thanks.